# How to write this dataframe to excel (xlsx)?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-xlsx

I have a dataframe of the following format:

[image]

What i want to do is write it to a .xlsx file as below (**everything in one sheet**):
[image]

Not fussed about the column names in the Excel file. Tried subsetting by `name` and using `cbind()` but it doesn't work as they have varying lengths. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way -

- Split the data by `name` in list of dataframes.
- Get the max number of rows from the list.
- Append `NA`'s to the dataframe with less number of rows and combine them together.
- Write to Excel with no column names.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('car', 'car', 'van', 'bus', 'bus', 'bus'), 
                 index = c(1, 2, 1, -1, 0, 1), 
                 value = c(10, 20, 15, 20, 25, 25))

tmp <- split(df, df$name)
n <- 1:max(sapply(tmp, nrow))

writexl::write_xlsx(do.call(cbind, lapply(tmp, `[`, n, )), 
                    'result.xlsx', col_names = FALSE)
```

This is how it looks in Excel.

[image]

Comment: lapply(tmp, `[`, n, ) - the way that works is just amazing

Answer (score 0):

Well another option is to convert the original data frame to a list containing unequal number of elements in each column. This list can then be converted to a data frame with padded columns.

The following code can be used:

```
# The original data frame
n <- c("car", "car", "van", "bus", "bus", "bus")
i <- c(1,2,1,-1,0,1)
v <- c(10,20,15,20,25,25)
df <- data.frame(name = n, index = i, value = v)

# The data frame is converted to a list
l <- list(
    "car" = rep("car", nrow(df[df$name == "car", ])), 
    "car_index" = df[df$name == "car", "index"], 
    "car_value" = df[df$name == "car", "value"], 
    "van" = rep("van", nrow(df[df$name == "van", ])), 
    "van_index" = df[df$name == "van", "index"], 
    "van_value" = df[df$name == "van", "value"], 
    "bus" = rep("bus", nrow(df[df$name == "bus", ])), 
    "bus_index" = df[df$name == "bus", "index"], 
    "bus_value" = df[df$name == "bus", "value"])

# The list column names
cols <- names(l)

# The maximum column length
max_len <- 0
for (col in cols){
    if (length(l[[col]]) > max_len)
        max_len <- length(l[[col]])
}

# Each column is padded
for (col in cols){
    l[[col]] <- c(l[[col]], rep("", max_len - length(l[[col]])))
}

# The list is converted to data frame
df_new <- as.data.frame(l)

# The data frame is written to xlsx file
writexl::write_xlsx(df_new, 'test.xlsx', col_names = FALSE)
```